# Сервер + Клиент

Tags: c#

Привет всем!
Пишу простой клиент+сервер.
Сервер генерит рандомное число каждую секунду и отправляет это число клиенту, клиент просто выводит числа на экран(в реальном времени)
Столкнулся с таким:
Невозможно вычислить выражение, поскольку фрейм машинного кода находится на вершине стека вызовов.
И это пишется везде, в смысле приложение вроде бы как работает, но на самом деле висит. А вот ошибка эта в отладчике, на пример в переменной sListener типа Socket
Сервер:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random rnd = new Random();
        public Form1()
        {
            Server();
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public void Server()
        {
            IPHostEntry ipHost = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            IPAddress ipAddr = ipHost.AddressList[1];
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 11000);

            Socket sListener = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            try
            {
                sListener.Bind(ipEndPoint);
                sListener.Listen(10);

                while (true)
                {
                    //label4.Text = "Ожидаем соединение через порт: " + ipEndPoint;

                    Socket handler = sListener.Accept();
                    string data = null;

                    string reply = label3.Text;

                    byte[] msg = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(reply);
                    handler.Send(msg);

                    if (data.IndexOf("<TheEnd>") > -1)
                    {
                        label4.Text = "Сервер завершил соединение с клиентом.";
                        break;
                    }

                    handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                    handler.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
            finally
            {
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
        private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int temp = rnd.Next(7000, 12000);
            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(temp);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Эээ... Что ж вы делаете-то, а? Вы зачем в конструкторе формы гоняете бесконечный цикл? Вы бы лучше выяснили, как писать многопоточные программы.

Comment: Да, я понял. Пытаюсь Server выполнить в новом потоке, вот так:
Thread my = new Thread(Server);
my.Start();
Но никак не могу понять почему он(метод) не выполняется. Если написать какой-нибудь простенький метод и вставить его вместо Server 
Thread my = new Thread(Example);
то Example успешно будет выполняться параллельно, а Server не хочет. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Вы плоховато объясняете, на мой взгляд. 
Попробуйте юзать async/await. Вот Вам пример даже http://pastebin.com/csjZj025
Кстати, с TCP удобнее работать используя TCPListener.
И ещё, Вы кажется путаете сервер и клиент. Ваш сервер сам никуда ничего не отправляет ежесекундно. Он ждёт подключения клиента.
И последнее, запуская `Server` в отдельном потоке, Вы не сможете получить значение из `label3`

Comment: "Вы не сможете получить значение из label3"
Это не страшно.
Число я генерирую внутри метода Server, да он ждет подключения, согласен. Сейчас метод Server у меня выполняется в таймере каждую секунду, из-за этого само окно приложения не показывается, все работает, но как бы в фоновом режиме, т.е. все, что я хотел сделать, все работает, сервер отправляет, клиент получает и строит график. Вот только хотелось бы что бы метод server выполнялся как то параллельно самой программе, что бы окошко отображалось

Comment: "Сейчас метод Server у меня выполняется в таймере каждую секунду," объясните мне, как Вы это делаете? У Вас бесконечный цикл в методе `Server`

Немного переделанный пример с msdn: http://pastebin.com/LPfMwhrF